# Записать в указаную строку текстогого файла значение переменной на bash

Tags: bash

Есть в наличии файл скажем test.txt с таким содержанием:

```
text1 
text2
3 
44 
text5
```

подскажите пожалуйста как на bash реализовать запись изменение скажем 3 строки, и по ходу выполнения скрипта изменять 5 строку и так далее,номер изменяемой строки также считывать из переменной, спасибо!

Comment: что тебе мешает создать доп файл с историей изменений? (если я правильно понял суть вопроса)

Comment: Не понял, вам 3 строку надо менять или 5? Покажите пример входных и выходных данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно брать номер строки из переменной, то просто подставьте
значение этой переменной в ваш скрипт.  Вот пример, который заменяет
третью строчку на `text3` и пятую строчку на
`text555` на *GNU sed*:

```sh
$ line=3
$ sed -e "${line}ctext3" -i -- ./txt.txt
$ line=5
$ sed -e "${line}ctext555" -i -- ./txt.txt
$
```

Вот те же действия с помощью более переносимого *POSIX ed*:

```sh
$ line=3
$ more <<-EOF | ed -s -- ./txt.txt
>    ${line}c
>    text3
>    .
>    wq
> EOF
$ line=5
$ more <<-EOF | ed -s -- ./txt.txt
>    ${line}c
>    text555
>    .
>    wq
> EOF
$
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Работает, я новичек  в bash ,но мне этот язык очень нравится, дня 4 шерстил интернет, остаюсь вам безмерно признательным!